# - Rendering problem - vitejs+vuejs+threejs

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I am in the process of making my portfolio and I decided for the first time to use the vitejs / vuejs + threejs combo.

And I have a first problem ... I created my canvas and I want to have a module in which I will build a 3D scene that I will use in the background with interactivity depending on the pages displayed.

I installed the library well and I imported my js module (in the index.html file ... is this the best way?)

To start with, I want to render the base scene with the red cube and unfortunately I only have the black screen (which responds well to the alpha property for example). But... my cube is not displayed and I do not understand why ?!?!?!

No error in the console and THREE is well instantiated...

Thanks for your help.

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
console.log(THREE)


/* Create Background Universe in canvas.webgl */

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

// Object
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

scene.add(mesh)

// Sizes
const sizes = {
    width: document.innerWidth,
    height: document.innerHeight
}

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height)
camera.position.z = 3
scene.add(camera)

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// ...

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    // alpha: true
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)

renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine if you use `window` instead of `document` when defining the dimensions of the renderer.

```js
/* Create Background Universe in canvas.webgl */

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

// Object
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000
})
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

scene.add(mesh)

// Sizes
const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
}

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height)
camera.position.z = 3
scene.add(camera)

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('#webgl')

// ...

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  // alpha: true
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)

renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.130.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
```

And yes, using the ESM version of `three.js` is absolutely fine.

Comment: Haha! Yes of course ! It immediately works better! ;) Thanks